# Create Database Instance from Model

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, visual-studio-2012, ef-model-first

*Seems like there is some confusion.  I created a SQL Server Compact Edition file and can see it from the Server Explorer.  I can also right click and add tables manually.  What I want to do is run the generated sqlce file to add all of the tables and columns from my model to the SDF.

-- background --

In Visual Studio 2012 (Ultimate), I designed a model using the model designer.  It created an edmx file.  I right clicked the model and chose "Generate Database from Model..." and created an sqlce file.  My understanding is that I should be able to execute this file on an sdf somehow to create a SQL Server Compact Edition Instance of my database.  I don't see the option on right click to execute the sql code, and the other option is to "Run SQL Scripts in Solution Explorer" which doesn't seem to make sense.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yea4bc1b.aspx  It says to drag the sqlce file to a database reference, but I'm not really sure what they mean.  I have tried to drag it to the server explorer where the sdf is connected.

I tried right clicking on the sdf in the Server Explorer to do New SQL Query and pasting the sqlce in, but it seems that Create Table isn't supported.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Generate Database from Model...* only generates tables and relationships.

You need to have a database created already, and have it in the Database References folder. Then you drag your script file to that database reference, as described in your mentioned link.